# Получить результат формы во всплывающем окне

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery, ajax

Есть форма регистрации нового пользователя, которая по умолчанию результат обработки отправляет на страницу `confirm.php`. А я хочу сделать так, чтобы результат срабатывал и отображался во всплывающем окне без перехода на другую страницу. Вот набросал [фидл](http://jsfiddle.net/vGAsL/63/), но в какую сторону дальше двигаться пока не могу понять

```js
function closeSelf() {
  self.close();
  return true;
}
$('.confirmation').submit(function() {
  $.ajax({
    success: function(data) {
      $(".confirmation").magnificPopup({
        items: {
          src: '#confirmation',
          type: 'inline'
        }
      });
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="/system/wpacert" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="return closeSelf()" name="certform" action="confirm.php">
  <input type="text" value="Имя" />
  <input type="password" value="Пароль" />
  <div>Сертификат:
    <input type="file" name="cert1" />
  </div>

  <div>
    <input class="confirmation" type="submit" value="Добавить" />
  </div>
</form>
<div id="confirmation" class="mfp-hide">
  <h2>Результат</h2>
  <p>Имя</p>
  <p>Пароль</p>
  <p>Сертификат №</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Так открывай МА после успешной регистрации, в чём проблема? Проблемы не вижу.

Comment: @ikerya проблема в том, что идет переход на след станицу, а мне нужно оставаться на этой же, но при этом, чтобы запрос отрабатывал

Answer (score 1):

Подобный вопрос обсуждался в данной теме
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7845866/how-to-set-the-input-value-in-a-modal-dialogue

```
$('#modal-from-dom').bind('show',function()
            {
                $(".modal-body #wall-post").val($("#linkURL").val());
            });

<html>
```

Пример страницы

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Example</title>
  <script src="scripts/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="scripts/bootstrap-modal.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="scripts/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" />

  <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function()
            {
                $('#modal-from-dom').bind('show',function()
                {
                    $(".modal-body").html($("#linkURL").val());
                });
            });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
  <!-- The Modal Dialog  -->
          <div id="modal-from-dom" class="modal hide fade">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <a href="#" class="close">&times;</a>
                <h3>Add Link</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
            <!--
            <form id='post-on-wall' method='POST' action='savePost.php' enctype='multipart/form-data'>"
        <input type='text' class='label-inline' name='linkURL' id='wall-post' value=linkURL>
            </form>
            -->
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <a href="#" class="btn primary">Add Link</a>
            </div>
        </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="wall-post">
        <textarea class='label-inline' name='linkURL' id='linkURL'></textarea>
        <button data-controls-modal="modal-from-dom" data-backdrop="true" data-keyboard="true" class="btn">Add Link</button>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
```

В Вашем случае вы хотите чтоб в модальном окне появлялись данные внесенные пользователем в форму или же чтоб отображался ответ от сервера?

Если второе, то необходимо использовать AJAX.

**Update:**

Вашу задачу примерно понял.
По-быстрому отредактировал пример.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
          $(function() {
            $( "#dialog" ).dialog();
             });
        $.ajax({url: "/system/wpacert", success: function(result){
            $("#dialog").html(result);
        }});
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog"></div>
<button>Получить результат</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: все правильно, чтобы отображался ответ от сервера - пока пришел к такому варианту http://jsfiddle.net/vGAsL/64/

Comment: Попробуйте отредактированный пример и дайте нам знать, пожалуйста, о результатах. Если что-то не получится - задавайте вопросы.

Comment: вообще таким способом ничего не получается, ни модальное окно не появляется и страница при всем перезагружается

Comment: Судя по описанию у Вас не подгрузились скрипты. Поправил Update вариант. Пробуйте

Comment: попробовал - появляется бледное, еле заметное всплывающее окно с надписью "basic dialog" и страница перезагружается, т.е. `ajax` не срабатывает...

Comment: А что у Вас за данные по этой ссылке? /system/wpacert . В каком виде хранятся? В консоле браузера есть ошибки? Запускаете страницу через http:// или через file:// ?

Comment: в фидле это страница фейк, а на реал - на ту же страницу ставлю перебрасывать. смотря в каком виде подавать - отсюда есть ошибки в консоли или нет. запускаю через http:// Может, продолжим обсуждение в чате?

Comment: Да, можно в чате обсудить.

Answer (score 0):

> @ikerya проблема в том, что идет переход на след станицу, а мне нужно оставаться на этой же, но при этом, чтобы запрос отрабатывал

При использовании form, не перенаправить не удастся. Используй $.get || $.post || $.ajax

Comment: я использую `ajax` и вот, что получаю http://jsfiddle.net/vGAsL/64/